# How to create subtraction's function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, addition, subtraction

1. I'm trying to do addition-to add all the price & subtraction-to subtract the price function
2. the result as decimal/float

```js
$('.add').keyup(function () {
    
    var sum = 0;

    $('.add').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    $('#total').val(sum);

});
```

```html
<strong>price1 : </strong>
<input type="text" name="IT" class="add" style="width:150px" required><br><br>

<strong>price2 : </strong>
<input type="text" name="roadtax" class="add" style="width:150px" required><br><br>

<strong>price3 : </strong>
<input type="text" name="servis" class="add" style="width:150px" required><br><br>

<strong>price4 : </strong>
<input type="text" name="other" class="add" style="width:150px" required><br><br>

<strong>discount : </strong>
<input type="text" name="disc" class="sub" style="width:150px" required><br><br>

<strong>total : </strong>
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" style="width:150px">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
```

1. Can do subtraction
2. I expect the output will be in decimal/float

Comment: _"I expect the output will be in decimal/float"_ - It will be if you input decimals/floats. If you only input integers, you will get an integer back.

Answer (score 0):

If i get your get your question right, this should help you.

1. Listen also for events of the `sub`-inputs.
2. Substract the value of the `sub`-inputs.
3. Call `toFixed` on the sum to get decimal output.

```js
$('.add, .sub').keyup(function () { // 1
    
    var sum = 0;

    $('.add').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    
    $('.sub').each(function() {
        sum -= Number($(this).val()); // 2
    });

    $('#total').val(sum.toFixed(2)); // 3

});
```

```html
<strong>price1 : </strong><input type="text" name="IT" class="add" style="width:150px" required><br><br>
<strong>price2 : </strong><input type="text" name="roadtax" class="add" style="width:150px"required><br><br>
<strong>price3      : </strong><input type="text" name="servis" class="add" style="width:150px"required><br><br>
<strong>price4  : </strong><input type="text" name="other" class="add" style="width:150px"required><br><br>
<strong>discount : </strong><input type="text" name="disc" class="sub" style="width:150px"required><br><br>
<strong>total : </strong><input type="text" id="total" name="total" style="width:150px">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.add').keyup(
    var sum = 0;

    $('.add').forEach(function() {
        sum += $(this).val();
    });

    sum -= $('.sub').val();

    $('#total').val(sum);
});
```

Or, if that doesn't work, then you can give each textbox it's own unique id (like id="roadTax") then you could do this:

```
$('.add').keyup(
    var sum = 0;

    sum += $("#roadTax").val();
    sum += $("#services").val();
    sum += $("#other").val();

    sum -= $('#discount').val();

    $('#total').val(sum);
});
```